# i want to show a pdf without showing print and download button and option by right click in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove save and print toolbar from my PDF.

This hides the download button but still showing download option by right click.

`<embed  src="publicMedia/fprefaces/first.pdf#toolbar=0" width="100%" height="100%" oncontextmenu= "return false;" >`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `toolbar=0` to `&navpanes=0&scrollbar=1`. I think that's what you're looking for - this will remove the download at the top, you'll still be able to 'Save as' on right click.

Comment: i want to remove  'Save as' on right click, what i do?